# Check no of occurance of all digits in array using single for Loop or use Any Collection

Tags: java, for-loop, collections

```
Integer a[]={10,20,30,10,10,20,50,60,50,50};

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{

             int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {

                if(a[i]==a[j])
                {
                    count++;

                }
            }
            System.out.println(a[i]+" occurs times ="+count);
            count=0;
}
```

Comment: Use `HashMap `.

Comment: Please add more detail to the question. Your question title does not relate in any clear way to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the output with no duplicate message with one loop

consider using `Set` to remove duplicate number

Look at this code:

```
Integer a[] = { 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 50, 60, 50, 50 };
Set<Integer> noDuplicateInt = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer integer : a) {
    if (noDuplicateInt.add(integer)) {
        System.out.println("Number of Occurence of " + integer + ": " +
                   Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(a), integer));
    }
}
```

---

**Update With Regards To Comment**

This is the same code without using `Collections` class:

```
Integer a[] = { 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 50, 60, 50, 50 };
Set<Integer> noDuplicateInt = new HashSet<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> numOccurenceMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer integer : a) {
    if (noDuplicateInt.add(integer)) {
        numOccurenceMap.put(integer, 1);
    } else {
        numOccurenceMap.replace(integer, numOccurenceMap.get(integer) + 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(numOccurenceMap);
```

Comment: thanks...can you tell me how to do the same without using collection ?

Comment: Do you mean without using `Collections` class, or/and without using `Set`

Comment: With one loop too

Comment: i want only using arrays (using single for loop ) not using Collections,Set,list and Map

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it without using `Collections` and with one loop, only if you make another loop on another 2D array that will save the integer and its number of occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer a[] = {10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 50, 60, 50, 50};
Map<Integer, Integer> integerIntegerMap =
        Stream.of(a).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, o -> o.getValue().size()));
System.out.println(integerIntegerMap);
```

Output:

`{50=3, 20=2, 10=3, 60=1, 30=1}`

Comment: Or even shorter: `Map<Integer, Long> integerIntegerMap = Arrays.stream(a).
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int i : a){
    map.compute(i, ( key, value ) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
}
```

Which results in `map` containing the items in the array `a` as **Keys** and the amount of occurances of that item as the **Value**

Comment: Shorter: `map.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following piece of code:

```
 public class HelloWorld{

    public int static[] apps = new int[10]; // stores the nr. of appearences of each digit

    public static int calcNr(int a) // calculates for each element in the array
    {
        while(a>0)
        {
            apps[a%10]++;
            a = a/10;
        }
    }

    public static calcArray(int [] v)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<v.length; i++)
            calcNr(v[i]);
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        //...
        int n; // nr of elements
        int [] array = new array[n];
        calcArray(array);
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that two loops?

Comment: This answer is very static... only works with numbers multiplied by `10`